# Wcf in Wpf missing service but have Iservice

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

A WCF file.

```
namespace DatabaseTransferViaWcf
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int generateId();
    }
}
```

The corresponding file.

```
namespace DatabaseTransferViaWcf
{
     public class Service1 : IService1
     {
         public int generateId()
         {
             return 5700 ;
         }
    }
}
```

I added them to my WPF Project as a service reference called "SendRecieveData".

How I am trying to use it.

```
public partial class Transfer : Window
{
    private void button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceHost host = null; 
        try
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SendRecieveData.Service1)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press <enter /> to terminate service.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            wcfHostId = wcf.generateId();
            textBox5.Text = "" + wcfHostId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error = " + ex.Message);
        } 

    }
}
```

It says I am missing a reference to Service1 but all the tutorials and blogs I have looked at don't have any more steps to them.

Comment: You need to post the exact exception details. "it says I am missing a reference..." is not enough.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Service1' does not exist in the namespace Client.SendRecieveData' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF application is a client of your service so you shouldn't use `ServiceHost` class. It is used if you want to host a service within your application. It is not your case. In your situation you should just use a proxy generated automatically when you added a service reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your service reference has not been added correctly. Try removing it and make sure you name it Service1 and not Service1Service or something similar.

EDIT:
Try something like

```
Service1Client service1Client = new service1Client();
Console.WriteLine(service1Client.generateId());
```

It is usually how the services are named.